# Как правильно сортировать строки с типом timestamp

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql, запрос

День добрый.

Есть одна таблица `orders`, содержащая в себе всего лишь 2 столбца. 
`order` - номер заказа в `int`, вида 12584 или 9536. 
`date` - время в формате `timestamp`, когда заказ был занесен в бд, вида '2018-03-21 15:56:14'.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь получить количество заказов в день, при помощи следующей функции

```
SELECT COUNT(*), 
       date 
  FROM orders 
 WHERE date >= '2018-02-23' AND date < '2018-02-28 23:59:59' 
 GROUP BY date 
 ORDER BY date;
```

Но это неверно, так как он выводит количество заказов в единицу времени.

Прошу помочь правильно написать запрос. Спасибо.

Comment: приведи дату к виду '2018-02-28', например так `date_trunc('day', date)` или используя `to_char`

Comment: лень писать в виде ответа: вообще то для этого существует конструкция `between`

Comment: @Barmaley так вопрос в том, как сделать группировку, а не как выбрать интервал

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT count(*),
       date_trunc('day', date) AS d
  FROM orders
 WHERE date between '2018-02-23' AND '2018-02-28 23:59:59'
 GROUP BY d
 ORDER BY d;
```

Comment: А постгре group by правда можно написать, обращаясь к алиасу создаваемой колонки?

Comment: Чаще всего нет, только в таком простом запросе

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*), 
       date_trunc('day', date)
  FROM orders 
 WHERE date >= '2018-02-23' AND date < '2018-02-28 23:59:59' 
 GROUP BY date 
 ORDER BY date_trunc('day', date);
```